# Transform data with multiple variables in wide format with header for each group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 df <- structure(list(status = c("case", "case", "case", "case", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", 
"unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown"), Ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("AA", 
"Asian", "Hispanic", "NHW"), class = "factor"), `<65` = c(29L, 
13L, 63L, 1215L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 75L, 23L, 43L, 385L, 6L, 5L, 
19L, 126L), `<70` = c(45L, 25L, 109L, 2321L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
124L, 36L, 76L, 633L, 14L, 6L, 23L, 166L), `<75` = c(73L, 47L, 
167L, 3704L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 174L, 52L, 103L, 863L, 29L, 7L, 
33L, 220L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

I need to convert this to wide format like this below with header for each group. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a table output like flextable/huxtable/DT? R data.frame structure doesn't work well with headers generally.

Comment: I need to create the table at least in that order. I can manually add the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to solve this problem using `melt()` and `dcast()`, from the **reshape2** package.

Here is the code:

```
# load environment
library(reshape2)
# summarize values
df = melt(df, id.vars = 1:2, measure.vars = 3:5)
df = dcast(df, Ethnicity ~ status + variable)
# print output
print(df)
```

Here is the output:

```
  Ethnicity case_<65 case_<70 case_<75 control_<65 control_<70 control_<75 MCI_<65 MCI_<70 MCI_<75 unknown_<65 unknown_<70 unknown_<75
1        AA       29       45       73           0           0           0      75     124     174           6          14          29
2     Asian       13       25       47           0           0           0      23      36      52           5           6           7
3  Hispanic       63      109      167           0           0           0      43      76     103          19          23          33
4       NHW     1215     2321     3704           0           1           1     385     633     863         126         166         220
```

I hope it helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_wider(Ethnicity, names_from = status, values_from = c(`<65`,`<70`,`<75`))
```

This code will get the column names, but you may need to reorder it using `select`.